# has_many through form new method, no id, no elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

I've been hacking around with Rails 3.2.11 for a while, and am trying to do this the 'right' way.

I have three models (Reflection, Skill, Utilization) that relate to each other through has_many: through:

**Utilization.rb**

```
class Utilization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :reflection, :skill, :used_skill #used_skill is a boolean
  belongs_to :reflection
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

**Reflection.rb**

```
class Reflection < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## attributes here ##
  has_many :utilizations
  has_many :skills, through: :utilizations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :utilizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills
end
```

**Skill.rb**

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## attributes here ##

  has_many :utilizations
  has_many :reflections, through: :utilizations
end
```

Within the app, skills are already defined. The user action I am trying to support is:

1. User gets form for new Reflection.
2. User sees a list of Skills and checks off which ones they have used (Utilization).
3. User posts to create new Reflection and create the associated Utilization objects.

Here is the new method **reflection_controller.rb**:

```
class ReflectionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @reflection = Reflection.new
    Skill.all.each do |skill|
      @reflection.utilizations.build(skill_id: skill.id, used_skill: false)
    end
  end
end
```

And an abbreviated **_form.html.erb** for Reflections

```
<%= form_for(@reflection) do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :utilizations do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :used_skill %>
    <%= builder.check_box :used_skill %>
    <%= builder.fields_for :skill do |skill| %>
      <%= skill.label :description %>
      <%= skill.text_field :description %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So the problem is that even though there are multiple Skills and I .new the Utilization objects and associate them with the @reflection, *they don't show up in the form*. I've played with the data structures a little bit, and I can reach the point where in `ReflectionController.new` @reflection.utilizations contains Utilization objects, it still won't work; when I run `@reflection.utilizations.count` it returns `0`. It looks like the problem is that since none of the objects have an `id` at that time, it simply will not render out in the form. But my understanding is that one should not `create` objects during the `new` method…

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Is there a better way to do this? I've seen examples, include Ryan Bates' Railscast where people just use code like:

```
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  3.times do
    question = @survey.questions.build
    4.times { question.answers.build }
  end
end
```

and supposedly this works fine.

**I really appreciate the help.** Trying to figure this out has been driving me crazy. This is my first question on SO, and I'm happy to add any clarifying data or additional code if you think it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use =:

```
  <%#### Here ####%>
  <%= f.fields_for :utilizations do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :used_skill %>
    <%= builder.check_box :used_skill %>
    <%#### and here ####%>
    <%= builder.fields_for :skill do |skill| %>
```

Comment: I appreciate the rapid response. Yes. I feel like a dolt. Thanks!